# force:inputField displays in .app but not in .cmp

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds, inputfield, forceinputfield

So I have multiple picklists I wish to dynamically display on my lightning component. But when it does not render at all on my component. I moved the code over to my .app and it displayed 100%.

Im hoping im missing something small.

Here is the code that works 100% in my .app but not in my .cmp

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <c:myComp />
<aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" 
                    default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact' }"/>
    <force:inputField aura:id="contactName" 
                      value="{!v.contact.Name}"/>

    <br /><br />

    <aura:attribute name="newFinding" type="Audit_Finding_Recommendation_Action__c"
                    default="{'sobjectType':'Audit_Finding_Recommendation_Action__c',
                             'Subject__c':'',
                             'Description__c':'',
                             'Status__c':'Not Started',
                             'Priority__c':'',
                             'Audit_Section__c':''}"/>

    <force:inputField value='{!v.newFinding.Status__c}' aura:id='newFindingStatus'/>
</aura:application>
```

Status__c is a picklist field.
Neither the basic Contact input field or my custom field displays on my component, no error and the html doesn't render the call. Am I missing an implementation of sorts or something along those lines?

Comment: This piece of code works perfect if I replace the Audit_Finding_Recommendation_Action__c with some existing object in my org.

Comment: Your code works for me in both a component and app too. Is the force:inputField enclosed in any other component or HTML tags? There's a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E4G3QAK) where force:inputField does not appear when inputField is enclosed in another tag.

Comment: Thanks @DianaWidjajaMyerscough I found out that is indeed the problem. I call this component within another component that renders it in an html container. The moment I move it out, it works. Will have to find another way around it seems.... :(